# Get date field based on Month and Year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got two fields, Period and YR with period representing the month.  I would like to be able to select these records as a date field with the assumption that the day is the last day of the month.  For example:

```
YR    Period      Date
2017   1          2017-01-31
2017   2          2017-02-28
Etc
```

I'm at a loss on how to go about doing this.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT YR, Period, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(YR, Period, 1)) AS [Date]
FROM <<table>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it using "basic" functions:

```
; with data as (
     select 2017 as yr, 1 as period 
     union all 
     select 2017 as yr, 2 as period
    )
    , temp as (
    select 
      yr, 
      period, 
      dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, 
                convert(datetime, cast(yr*10000 + period*100 + 1 as varchar))
                       )
     ) as test
    from data
    )
    select yr, period, convert(varchar(10), test, 126) from temp
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: @SqlZim thank you for the suggestion; I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: One more thing, instead of building a string of yyyy-m-dd, it would be better to build a string of yyyymmdd. [#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/)

Comment: The yyyy-mm-dd issue, I had completely missed it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another query:

```
WITH tb(YR,Period)AS(

    SELECT 2017,1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017,3 
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,tb.Period+1, DATEADD( YEAR, YR-1900,0))) FROM tb
```

```
-----------------------
2017-02-28 00:00:00.000
2017-03-31 00:00:00.000
2017-04-30 00:00:00.000
```